# How to tab seperated txt file to csv in python

Tags: python, csv

I have a txt file of 7 columns and about 8000 rows. 
the name of the file is "Azimuth"

The first row-
Id Xs Xe Ys Ye Length Azimuth

and each row under is a unique measurement.
so this is a txt file with 8000 measurements.
the data is tab separated or so it seems in the file itself.

when i open it with Excel it converts it to columns and rows with no problem, but when i try to read it with python, it reads the whole text as one column.

i tried to run this code that I found:

```
f=open("Azimuth.txt")
lines=f.readlines()
result=[]
for x in lines:
      result.append(x.split(' ')[0])
f.close()
print result
```

when i run it, the it prints the whole txt file as one long row (or column, i'm not sure). 
I tried to convert it to csv file but that separated the whole txt by commas, not as i was expected.

anyone can help? 
i need to build a code that relies on that file separated to columns and rows.

I'm not a programmer, so i'll mention i use sublime editor and run the script with the terminal (it works properly, the script ends with .py and i used the #!/usr/bin/env python command)

thanks everyone

Comment: The [_non_-accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25516384/4116239) to "[Extract data from tsv file python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25516332/extract-data-from-tsv-file-python)" shows how to read and write TSV files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [csv](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/csv.html) module, using `tab` as the delimiter:

```
import csv
with open("Azimuth.txt") as f:
   rows = csv.reader(f, delimiter="\t")
   for row in rows:
      # do whatever
```

If you want a list of all the rows you can `rows = list(csv.reader(f, delimiter="\t"))` but you can iterate a row at a time using the logic above. You also never need to call `readlines()` unless you actually  want a list, in python you can iterate over the file object so if you were to parse manually, you could:

```
with open("Azimuth.txt") as f:
  rows = [line.split("\t") for line in f]
```

Or line by line:

```
 with open("Azimuth.txt") as f:
     for line in f:
       row = line.split("\t")
       # use row ...
```

Comment: that worked great, thank you. I have some questions:

1. when i tried
for i in rows: print i[1], it did print the 2nd columns as expected, but when i tried- for i in rows: 
g=20  
h=50
if i[7] > g and i[7] < h: print i[7]
print i[7]

means, I tried to print the text between rows 20 and 50, only the 7th column.

my syntax is very wrong, offer for a with another solution?

also in another comment i got a suggestion to make rows into a list, and than work on it. here, as i printed type(rows), it is it  a csv.reader.  can i make commands on it just as i would on a list?

@Padraic Cunningham

Answer (score 0):

The problem is around your `.split()` function call. Try this instead:

```
f=open("Azimuth.txt")
lines=f.readlines()
result=[]
for x in lines:
      result.append(x.split('\t')[0])
f.close()
print result
```

However, since your file is in csv format, you might want to look at libs for this. Try either `import csv`, or using the lib panda if you need heavy computing on it : http://pandas.pydata.org/

Comment: it worked! 

but there is something that demands further explanation for me. 
you mentions that the file is in csv format, but it is actually in a txt format.  or am i wrong? i guess if it was just txt file than excel wouldn't be able to separate it properly?

Comment: There is no real difference between a CSV file and a text file - a CSV file is just a text file where there are several items on a line and they are separated by commas. Microsoft Windows may happen to assume you want to open a CSV with Excel and a text file with Notepad but that is just Microsoft, the contents of the file are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Python's [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#module-csv) module is perfectly suited for doing this as follows:

```
import csv

with open("Azimuth.txt", "rb") as f_input:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input, delimiter='\t')
    header = next(csv_input)
    result = list(csv_input)

print result
```

This will read each line of your tab separated file into `result` as a list-of-lists. If possible, use Python's `with` command to ensure the file is automatically closed afterwards.

`header` will hold the first row, as in:

```
['Id', 'Xs', 'Xe', 'Ys', 'Ye', 'Length', 'Azimuth']
```

To write out rows 534 to 673 with only columns 5 and 6, you could do the following:

```
import csv

with open("Azimuth.txt", "rb") as f_input:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input, delimiter='\t')
    result = list(csv_input)

with open("output.csv", "wb") as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerow([result[0][4], result[0][5]])       # first write the header for columns 5 and 6

    for row in result[534:674]:
        csv_output.writerow([row[4], row[5]])   # only columns 5 and 6
```

Note, this assumes the file is small enough to be read into memory. If this is not the case, then line by line processing would be needed.

This would use the default `csv` format of using a comma. You can of course specify your own delimiter to use with the `delimiter` parameter for the `csv.writer` if required.

In case you were wondering, Python numbering starts from `0`, so the first column would be `row[0]`.

Comment: thank you, looks like it worked well, it is possible to extract the new csv file? i assume its the "csv_input"

Comment: It would be straight forward to write `result` to a file, but what format would you need? And would the data need processing in some way first?

Comment: i need to do some elementary commands first, for example- extract rows 534 to 673, or extract the same rows but only columns 5 and 6. 

these are just simple examples. 
so i guess what is best for me to do is to keep with this script, but to make all the command on the "result"

Comment: well I did ran the code, some of it goes really well, for example when i print result[0] it does print the header as it should. 

when i tried the 2nd part of the code, i tried to print csv_output but it returns: <_csv.writer object at 0x1004cc940> instead of printing the header (not sure yet how the [0][4] and [0][5] prints back the header).

after this i tried the last part of the code, and it prints back many rows (534:674) with the repeating :
<_csv.writer object at 0x100606940>

Comment: i'll try to tag so you might see this comment
@Martin Evans

Comment: `result` holds all of your input data. `csv_output` is a `csv` object that is used to write out each row to the new file called `output.csv`, so printing it will not display a row. `[0][4]` is just the first row, fifth column in the data.